# How to load the icon of a website with LPMetadataProvider? (LinkPresentation)

Tags: swift, url, swiftui, metadata

If I send the URL `https://support.apple.com/en-us/102651` via iMessages I get a preview of the metadata:

[image]

I guess Apple is using the [LinkPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation) framework for that. I'm only interested in the icon. However I am unable to load the `NSItemProvider`. For most URLs the item provider has a the type `public.image` and loading the icon/image works as expected, but some URLs, like the one mentioned above, only return item providers with strange types such as `"dyn.agq80w5pbq7ww88brrfv085u"`. But as the URL works in iMessages, there should probably be a way to load the image.

If you run the code below, you will see what I mean:

```
import LinkPresentation
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers.UTType

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var icon: Image?
//    let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com")! // Does work
     let url = URL(string: "https://support.apple.com/en-us/102651")! //Does not work

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let icon {
                icon
            }
            else {
                Text("no image")
            }

            Button("Get icon") {
                self.getIcon()
            }
        }
    }

    private func getIcon() {
        let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
        metadataProvider.shouldFetchSubresources = true
        metadataProvider.timeout = 15
        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: self.url) { metadata, _ in
            print("icon item provider: \(String(describing: metadata?.iconProvider))")

            metadata?.iconProvider?.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { item, error in
                if let error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
                if let imageData = item as? Data {
                    self.icon = Image(nsImage: NSImage(data: imageData)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```